# `pg_query_params` and too many parameters

Tags: php, postgresql

One can query a database with the `pg_query_params` method, for instance:

```
pg_query_params($connection, 'SELECT foo FROM bar WHERE id=$1 AND name=$2',array("Foobar","Qux"));
```

However when the query doesn't use all parameters, for instance with the `SELECT foo FROM bar WHERE id=$1` query, one receives the following error:

```
Query failed: ERROR: bind message supplies 2 parameters, but prepared statement "" requires 1
```

Why is `pg_query_params` so restrictive? One could "construct" the query and simply add tests dynamically. Can one "turn off" this behavior? What are the alternatives to offer a query that may (not) use less parameters than the provided once?

Comment: Some languages and tools let you bind named parameters from a hashmap/dictionary. I don't know if PHP does, but that's the usual solution to this. Otherwise, just append parameters to the array based on the actual query you're sending.

Comment: @CraigRinger: Of course appending parameters is a solution, but it makes the process way more complicated than it should be...

Answer (score 1):

It  is probably just wrapping the prepared statement syntax in postgres.

```
PREPARE fooplan (int, text, bool, numeric) AS
INSERT INTO foo VALUES($1, $2, $3, $4);
EXECUTE fooplan(1, 'Hunter Valley', 't', 200.00);
```

And as such will just catch the exception thrown by postgres if it's executing your statement with that extra variable.

[Postgresl Prepare Documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-prepare.html#SQL-PREPARE-EXAMPLES)

Edit: From having a look around it seems to call PQExecParams from the postgresql C library, libpq. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/libpq-exec.html#LIBPQ-PQEXECPARAMS

If you really need pg_query_params to take surplus arguments, why not just write a wrapper to preg_match the $[0-9] strings in the query and only supply the total amount of matches to the pg_query_params function.

For example:

```
function my_query_params( $conn, $query, $params )
{
     $matches = array();
     preg_match( '/[^\'"]\$[0-9]+[^\'"]/', $query, $matches );

     $params = array_slice( $params, 0, count( $matches ) - 1 );

     return pg_query_params( $conn, $query, $params );
}
```

I didn't test this at all but the idea is there.